# Rails Heroku App Signup Password Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

When I use my application in my development environment, my application works perfectly.

But when I deployed my application to Heroku and tried to signup to my application, it won't let me put in a password.

[image]

Here's my User Model: `User.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                     :on => :create,
                     :format => {:with => /\A.*(?=.{10,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\@\#\$\%\^\&\+\=]).*\Z/ }
  has_many :audio_uploads                   
end
```

Here's my Heroku Logs:

```
$ heroku logs
2016-04-27T16:04:27.364970+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (13.0ms)
2016-04-27T16:04:27.365465+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 965ms (Views: 94.6ms | ActiveRecord: 20.9ms)
2016-04-27T16:04:27.262809+00:00 app[web.1]:    (17.4ms)  BEGIN
2016-04-27T16:04:27.350926+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (79.9ms)
2016-04-27T16:04:27.374310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=c5e4e5d0-480e-453c-abf3-9a86fa60b0f2 fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=10ms service=1009ms status=200 bytes=3873
2016-04-27T16:06:32.067568+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 50.141.101.18 at 2016-04-27 16:06:32 +0000
2016-04-27T16:06:32.282443+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'thepengamestaff@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
2016-04-27T16:06:32.312029+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (22.7ms)
2016-04-27T16:06:32.285109+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-04-27T16:06:32.311864+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (3.0ms)
2016-04-27T16:06:32.071460+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ySEztEMIDhq/hsZLOUWKH/eZpO+v7+NAcIS0RxGVhk3nxuDjsYk9yPiwKuRi+XDKdArXy8qr3weyntYeV/S9AA==", "user"=>{"email"=>"thepengamestaff@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
2016-04-27T16:06:32.071366+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2016-04-27T16:06:32.279501+00:00 app[web.1]:    (4.5ms)  BEGIN
2016-04-27T16:06:32.313900+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
2016-04-27T16:06:32.314470+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 243ms (Views: 25.3ms | ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
2016-04-27T16:06:32.335067+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=35a5bfb8-23ad-4c1d-b783-2035e5fa0e8f fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=258ms status=200 bytes=3873
2016-04-27T16:06:32.808429+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=05e8f3ce-ac90-4d35-9726-6f91e4bba782 fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-04-27T16:40:06.984919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-04-27T16:40:06.985544+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-04-27T16:40:11.180065+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354742+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354744+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354745+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354733+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-04-27 16:40:12] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354748+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354747+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354746+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354749+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354751+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354752+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354745+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354754+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354751+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354753+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354750+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-04-27T16:40:12.355023+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354895+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-04-27 16:40:12] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-04-27T16:40:12.354839+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-04-27 16:40:12] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-04-27T16:40:13.585727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-04-27T17:49:35.113399+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by butlera10@gmail.com
2016-04-27T17:49:38.558164+00:00 heroku[run.3902]: Awaiting client
2016-04-27T17:49:38.699911+00:00 heroku[run.3902]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-04-27T17:49:38.973599+00:00 heroku[run.3902]: State changed from starting to up
2016-04-27T17:49:43.029983+00:00 heroku[run.3902]: State changed from up to complete
2016-04-27T17:49:43.018253+00:00 heroku[run.3902]: Process exited with status 0
2016-04-27T17:51:10.920591+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-04-27T17:51:10.920230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-04-27T17:51:14.342089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8932 -e production`
2016-04-27T17:51:19.362894+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-04-27 17:51:19] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-04-27T17:51:19.363274+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-04-27 17:51:19] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=8932
2016-04-27T17:51:19.362913+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-04-27 17:51:19] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
2016-04-27T17:51:19.454721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-04-27T17:51:20.024882+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:8932
2016-04-27T17:51:20.024883+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-04-27T17:51:20.132053+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.4ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:20.024872+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-04-27T17:51:20.110724+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2016-04-27T17:51:20.132629+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 14.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:20.024884+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-04-27T17:51:20.024884+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 50.141.101.18 at 2016-04-27 17:51:20 +0000
2016-04-27T17:51:20.127890+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:20.125833+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=0d454f0a-546a-40c7-8085-25fd8d0fb02c fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=115ms status=200 bytes=2620
2016-04-27T17:51:20.288579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-3582e87fbdf1e55fd025c03dcbe32000fe22cddf80be63eddce1f44d22b9ee7c.js" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=f586251a-cef4-4c22-8e6e-494331db811d fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-04-27T17:51:20.719781+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=6db42728-a63f-4618-aaf2-5dba282f36a2 fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-04-27T17:51:23.563573+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2016-04-27T17:51:23.560151+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 50.141.101.18 at 2016-04-27 17:51:23 +0000
2016-04-27T17:51:23.623466+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (10.3ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:23.663268+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (35.6ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:23.665809+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 102ms (Views: 81.8ms | ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:23.665325+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:23.658128+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_in" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=6049722d-848a-43f7-93e1-bb1ae068b706 fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=110ms status=200 bytes=3914
2016-04-27T17:51:33.696789+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 50.141.101.18 at 2016-04-27 17:51:33 +0000
2016-04-27T17:51:33.699641+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TcLY2YzEW4D3OhGowMV3h0aMyTzWDLKouohbJPcsbdBjJQuOfkVoUrAM/QebeY1SxR+6GLNIju94kjl9sU1WnQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"thepengamestaff@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2016-04-27T17:51:33.713266+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "thepengamestaff@gmail.com"]]
2016-04-27T17:51:33.714168+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:33.699526+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2016-04-27T17:51:33.908446+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (4.1ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:33.908608+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.5ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:33.910039+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.6ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:33.718033+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TcLY2YzEW4D3OhGowMV3h0aMyTzWDLKouohbJPcsbdBjJQuOfkVoUrAM/QebeY1SxR+6GLNIju94kjl9sU1WnQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"thepengamestaff@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2016-04-27T17:51:33.910498+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 12.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:33.717918+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2016-04-27T17:51:33.903135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/sign_in" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=ef250efe-466b-40be-b3dc-f55bb2cc1bca fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=233ms status=200 bytes=4175
2016-04-27T17:51:40.615501+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (5.0ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:40.616462+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 29.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:40.577392+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_up" for 50.141.101.18 at 2016-04-27 17:51:40 +0000
2016-04-27T17:51:40.584586+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2016-04-27T17:51:40.608974+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (4.7ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:40.609062+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.6ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:40.608241+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/sign_up" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=1c3bbc98-813d-4712-b3c3-d926f5cd7a14 fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=3583
2016-04-27T17:51:54.192489+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.0ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-04-27T17:51:53.964273+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 50.141.101.18 at 2016-04-27 17:51:53 +0000
2016-04-27T17:51:53.966775+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qIqYpSlM5lUgygup7G1kmoMMab4Xh0IhKl5r4ZXIuwyGbUvy283Vh2f85wa30Z5PAJ8amnLDfmboRAm406mAQQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"thepengamestaff@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
2016-04-27T17:51:54.202905+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.3ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:54.190025+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'thepengamestaff@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
2016-04-27T17:51:54.204785+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 238ms (Views: 9.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:53.966724+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2016-04-27T17:51:54.174839+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.4ms)  BEGIN
2016-04-27T17:51:54.204211+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:54.202757+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (2.1ms)
2016-04-27T17:51:54.197219+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=thepengame.herokuapp.com request_id=0f27d188-8023-4bac-8db9-d8fe488b0d11 fwd="50.141.101.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=246ms status=200 bytes=3873
```

Does anyone know why my signup form isn't letting me put in a valid password when I try to sign up?

I've put the password in the way I'm supposed to, but the form isn't letting me sign up.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you run migrations on heroku?

Comment: Yes, I have run migrations on Heroku.  It still gives me an error when I put in the password to sign up.

Comment: What your model looks like?

Comment: best way to debug it is `heroku logs`, can u provide it ?

Comment: I've provided my heroku logs.

Comment: @AB10 probably, that email already exist in database, try different email to sign up.

Comment: Oh OK, thanks! Can I clear the database with ($ heroku rake db:reset) command?